# Beamer \tableofcontents[currentsection] is shading subsubsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am using

```
\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{A continuación}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

and I have sections, subsections and subsubsections. The output I am receiving is

[image]

I would like sub-sub-secitons to have the same behavior as sub-sections.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{A continuación}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsubsectionstyle=show/show/
show/shaded]
    \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]